# How to add block plugins to grapesjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, grapesjs

This is my code and I have installed the node module too but it's not working.

```
var editor = grapesjs.init({
        showOffsets: 1,
        noticeOnUnload: 0,
        container: '#gjs',
        height: '100%',
        fromElement: true,
        plugins: ["gjs-blocks-basic"],
        pluginsOpts: {
          "gjs-blocks-basic": {
            block: {
              category: 'basic',
            }
          }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an extra key `block` inside plugin options, it should be category.

```
const editor = grapesjs.init({
        showOffsets: 1,
        noticeOnUnload: 0,
        container: '#gjs',
        height: '100%',
        fromElement: true,
        plugins: ["gjs-blocks-basic"],
        pluginsOpts: {
          "gjs-blocks-basic": {
            category: "Basic"
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

> customize plugin doesn't add in single quote

```
const editor = grapesjs.init({
        showOffsets: 1,
        noticeOnUnload:0,
        container: '#gjs',
        plugins: ['gjs-preset-webpage',myPlugin,'myNewComponentTypes' ],
        pluginsOpts: {
            'grapesjs-plugin-export': { /*option*/ },
             'myPlugin':{ category: "myPlugin"},
        },
```

> Make plugin in function [Reference](https://grapesjs.com/docs/modules/Plugins.html#basic-plugin)

```
 //PLUGIN

    
    function myPlugin(editor) {
        editor.BlockManager.add('my-block',{
            label:'Plug',
            category: 'Basic',
            content:'<div class="my-block"><p>Plugin Success</p></div>',
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    const editor = grapesjs.init({
      container: "#editor",
      fromElement: true,
      width: "auto",
      storeManager: false,
      plugins: [gjsBlockBasic],
      pluginsOpts: {
        gjsBlockBasic: {},
      },
      blockManager: {
        appendTo: "#blocks",
      },
    })
```

Add "blocks" to a div where you want to display block basic options.

```
    <div id="blocks"/>
```